# addClass to every div with data-attribute tag

Tags: jquery

How can I add CSS classes like `widget-00`, `widget-01` etc. to each of these divs via jQuery?

```
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="00">
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="01">
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="02">
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="03">
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you could use the attribute selector along with `addClass()`. If you provide a function to the latter then you can read the `data-widget-id` attribute value and use it in the class you apply to the element. Try this:

```js
$('[data-widget-id]').addClass(function() {   
  return `widget-${$(this).data('widget-id')}`;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-form other-classes" data-widget-id="00">Foo</div>
<div class="mdl-form other-classes" data-widget-id="01">Bar</div>
<div class="mdl-form other-classes" data-widget-id="02">Fizz</div>
<div class="mdl-form other-classes" data-widget-id="03">Buzz</div>
```

That said, it's worth noting that dynamically assigning classes at runtime is an anti-pattern. If you want to identify elements then you already have the `widget-id` you can select by, amongst other methods.

Comment: Pretty neat solution :)

Comment: I found new thing which is closure function in addClass, Thanx buddy :-)

Comment: No problem. It's a fantastic pattern which is used a lot in jQuery and helps avoid a lot of explicit loops.

Comment: I have tried now both snippets from you, **but none of it worked unfortunately.**

Is it possible that jQuery isn't doing anything?
I also tried some very simple stuff with no result, like:

        $(document).ready(function(){
         $( "body" ).prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
        });

jQuery is embeded via

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Browser console is not logging any errors.
Maybe it is because i want to add it to an openHAB sitemap, maybe there is some restriction to it?

Comment: This code should work fine, as can be seen in the snippet above. The only way I can think that it wouldn't is if the sitemap is adding the content to the DOM *after* the page loads, via AJAX for example. To test this you can do `console.log($('[data-widget-id]').length)` just before the above code.

Comment: Thats very interesting. I made two console logs:
console.log("Hello world!");
console.log($('[data-widget-id]').length);

Which gives me exactly:
Hello World!
0
Hello World!
0

... so yes, DOUBLE the entries! And empty values ...

Comment: Double entries is one issue, but the bigger problem is that the code is running before the elements exist in the DOM (hence length = 0). Without knowing how the page is setup, I can't really help with that, but that is the problem you need to address. Once you can run code after the elements exist, then the above example will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. Similar to Prateik's answer but I would select it by the attribute and not by one class of the div.

That way you also make sure that the `data-widget-id` attribute is present without having to check for it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-widget-id]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("widget-" + $(this).data('widget-id'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="00"></div>
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="01"></div>
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="02"></div>
<div class="mdl-form  mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-grid mdl-cell--12-col" data-widget-id="03"></div>
```

Comment: that's perfect I wish this was suggestion in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

the s do have closing tags, i didnt post it here.

I have tried now both snippets from you, **but none of it worked unfortunately.**
Personally i like the version by "Cornel Raiu" better, because there are many more  with class .mdl-form which i did not tell you (but should not be affected).

Is it possible that jQuery isn't doing anything?
I also tried some very simple stuff with no result, like:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "body" ).prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
    });
```

jQuery is embeded via

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Browser console is not logging any errors.
Maybe it is because i want to add it to an openHAB sitemap, maybe there is some restriction to it?